# @return self para que sirve

Tags: php

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy haciendo una aplicación con php en vs code y al descargar una extension que me genera los metodos get y set para mi modelo cuando genero los set me los genera de esta forma:

```
 /**
 * Set the value of value
 *
 * @return self
 */
public function setValue($value)
{
    $this->value = $value;

    return $this;
}
```

Y me pregunto cual es la funcion del `@return self`, he visto esto mismo tambien en otros lugares como frameworks de php o pequeñas librerías pero no he podido encontrar información al respecto. Desde ya gracias :)

Comment: No estoy seguro de dónde proviene esta sintaxis, pero es una forma de documentar el código, para que, por ejemplo, **IDEs** y **Editores** *(como Visual Studio Code)* entiendan que hace esta función. Si puedes ver que el método que tienes allí tiene un `return $this`, entonces el `@return self` indica que este método retorna el propio objeto al que pertenece, si no retornara nada tendría algo como `@return void`

Comment: Puedes echarle un ojo a [phpDocumentor](https://phpdoc.org/3.0/) tal vez te sirva de ayuda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquí hay dos cosas importantes:

1. `@return self` en comentarios es solo para documentación y que algunas extensiones de autocompletado del IDE puedan saber que se devuelve una instancia de la clase. En caso de estar en el código, el método debería ser declarado como estático, pero eso está fuera del tema de tu pregunta.
2. `return $this;` devuelve la instancia de la clase, de forma que puedas encadenar otros métodos, por ejemplo, vamos a suponer que tu clase tiene dos métodos (setValue y setName):

```
$miClase = new MiClase();
$miClase->setValue('125')->setName('Juan Pérez');
```

En caso de no tener ese `return $this;` no podrías encadenar los métodos y debes hacer las llamadas por separado:

```
$miClase = new MiClase();
$miClase->setValue('125');
$miClase->setName('Juan Pérez');
```

Comment: Gracias, ahora ya que que hacen :)

Comment: Solo como extra esta técnica se llama `Method chaining`  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining